# What is the difference between Ruby open class and JavaScript prototype object?

Tags: javascript, ruby

In Ruby you can use openclass to add some properties like this:

```
class String
   attr_accessor :ruby
   def open
      ruby = 'open'
   end
   def close
      ruby = 'close'
   end
end
```

Then you can use

```
x = String.new
x.open # it will set ruby to 'open'
'open'
x.close # it will set ruby to 'close'
'close'
```

In JavaScript you can use prototype to add properties like this:

```
String.prototype.ruby = {}
String.prototype.open = function () { this.ruby = "open"; }
String.prototype.close = function () { this.ruby = "close"; }
```

Then you can invoke these prototype methods like this:

```
var x = new String()
console.log(['ruby', x.ruby].join(':'))
/* when invoke open */
x.open()
console.log(['ruby', x.ruby].join(':'))
/* when invoke close */
x.close()
console.log(['ruby', x.ruby].join(':'))
```

Are they the same thing?

Comment: Your methods `open` and `close` in Ruby do not work the way you probably intended.

Comment: @sawa which situation don't work?

Comment: It's so long since that comment, so I don't know if my comment is relevant at that time, but here on Ruby 3 the `attr_accessor :ruby` define `@ruby`, not `ruby`, so you are just creating a local variable that get destroyed when the function ends.